# Jquery IE issue while getting the status of a radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm wrapping some radion button to give them a better style, using css and jquery to handle the radion selection.

I'm using this HTML to wrap the radio input element:

```
<button class="radio-button inches inches-selected">
    <input type="radio" id="inches" name="unit" value="inches" checked="checked">
</button>
```

All works well as expected in each browser, but in IE when I try to get the checked status (set by default in the HTML) I get "undefined".

I've tried:

```
$("#inches").is(":checked");
$("#inches").attr("checked");
$("input[value=inches]").is(":checked");
```

but I always get "undefined".

Any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe an `<input/>` wrapped within a `<button/>` is the problem. What is 'undefined', the exact error message ?

Comment: `document.getElementById("inches").checked` ? Wrapping an input with a button seems a strange way to go about things - have you tried wrapping it in a label element and styling that? Have you confirmed that the jQuery selector works? E.g., what do you get with `alert($("#inches").length);` or `$("#inches")[0].checked`?

Comment: No error messages, the code simply doesn't work because it cannot find the element. With firebug-lite (js version) i cannot see the input in the DOM. Maybe I should try keeping the <input> outside the button... it was implemented with jquery itself (done at runtime) and it worked well on every browser, then I thought to remove that js to do it directly with HTML... I think I'll make again use of the JS version.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think you could wrap an `<input>` in a `<button>`. But assuming you can, you should not use the selector `$("input[value=inches]")` since that would also select any other input elements (e.g. text boxes) that have `inches` as its current value. Other than that, I'm not familiar with the button wrapping technique so I am suspicious of that approach overall.